# python: opencv,some issue when count pixel

Tags: python, file, opencv, path, working-directory

I use opencv to count the number of white and black pixels of picture(I have convert them into black and white image), and everytime I run my code it return the number is 0,and the code is

```
output_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset_demo/result_pic"

for pic in os.listdir(output_path):
  if pic.endswith('.jpg'):
    image = cv2.imread(pic,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    number_of_white_pix = np.sum(image == 255)
    number_of_black_pix = np.sum(image == 0)
    number_of_total = number_of_white_pix + number_of_black_pix
    number_of_ratio = number_of_white_pix / number_of_black_pix
    print(number_of_total)
```

Comment: did you notice that `image is None`? debug your code before asking. -- [tour], [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pic variable contains only the file name of the image, but cv2.imread needs the full path to the image in order to read it. You need to use the full path to the image when you call cv2.imread.

```
output_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/dataset_demo/result_pic"

for pic in os.listdir(output_path):
  if pic.endswith('.jpg'):
    pic = os.path.join(output_path, pic) #full path to the image
    image = cv2.imread(pic,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    number_of_white_pix = np.sum(image == 255)
    number_of_black_pix = np.sum(image == 0)
    number_of_total = number_of_white_pix + number_of_black_pix
    number_of_ratio = number_of_white_pix / number_of_black_pix
    print(number_of_total)
```

Comment: thanks! It seems that I am reading a path not a image, and it worked now! Thanks again!

Comment: well it doesn't need the full (absolute) path, relative would work too. it needs a **correct path.** `os.path.join` is definitely the right thing to use here.

Comment: yes, my mistake is I read the path instead of an image, os.path.join certainly will work! Thanks too!